# Porting a fork of a software to a new version

Tags: git, version-control

I have a pretty big fork, of a pretty humongous software sitting in a git repository. Since our version and the upstream have diverged significantly, the decision was made to port over to the current version.

So, what would be the best way to do this? Is there some way to mark a particular git commit with a flag notifying that is is already ported over? Or should I just try some complex rebasing scheme?

I'm mainly asking from the standpoint of the logistics, as I will definitely be pushing some of the features to upstream (thus rebased against the current head), but most of the code needs to be updated and kept in our fork.

Comment: I think you'll want to look into git's built in merge function as it is very powerful. http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: Have you tried to rebase or merge your fork, to see how many conflicts are triggered ?

Comment: @LeGEC Way to many, they actually changed the code style of the entire code base twice between my version and their version :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a tricky merge ahead!  I'd suggest you take a look at [`git imerge`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) which helps with large merge problems by breaking them down into smaller pieces.  To quote the project page:

> `git-imerge` has two primary design goals:
>
> - Reduce the pain of resolving merge conflicts to its unavoidable minimum, by finding and presenting the 
>     smallest possible conflicts: those between the changes introduced by one commit from each branch.
> - Allow a merge to be saved, tested, interrupted, published, and collaborated on while it is in progress.

If you follow the `git-imerge` process you'll be presented with a series of relatively small merge conflicts that you can fix one-by-one.  I'd encourage you to run any automated tests you have (or at a minimum, compile your project) after each resolution step to reduce the risk of introducing bugs as you go.

Whether you want the end result of this process to be a merge commit, or a rebase of your commits onto the upstream branch is up to you, `git imerge` lets you choose either of these options (and some others) as a clean-up step once you've completed the hard part of actually combining the changes.

Comment: I don't think merge is suitable for this particular use-case. I would just end up with a jumbled mix of two versions with no possibility to send patches to the upstream.

Comment: Hi @Let_Me_Be, if you take a look at https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge#simplifying-results you'll see that git-imerge can use the resolutions you give it to rebase your code onto the upstream branch, and if the forks have diverged significantly then you're less likely to hit major conflicts that you can't work through using imerge then git rebase.